# Django Cookiecutter over https

Tags: python, django, ssl, nginx, certificate

It is slightly over 4 hours now, and I cannot get my nginx server to work with my SSL certificates for my Django application.

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    upstream app {
        server django:5000;
    }

    server {
        listen                  80;
        server_name             www.example.com;
        rewrite ^/(.*)          https://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
    }

    server {
        listen                  443 ssl;
        server_name             www.example.com;
        charset                 utf-8;

        ssl                     on;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/1_www.example.com_bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/example_rsa.key;

        location / {
            try_files           $uri                    @proxy_to_app;
        }

        location @proxy_to_app {
            proxy_pass          http://app;
            proxy_redirect      off;

            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    Host                    $http_host;
        }

    }
}
```

I did manage to redirect all `http` traffic to `https`, but when I visit `https://www.example.com` I get a beautiful `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

The only related part I can think of in my Django application is:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```

but I do think that the problem is at nginx level. I am using [Django Cookiecutter](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) by [pydanny](https://github.com/pydanny). The unmodified nginx.conf file can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/compose/nginx/nginx.conf). I did edit the Dockerfile to `ADD` my certificates.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see it allows 443 connections. Check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/security/#ssl-https to make sure you're in the right path (beside cookiecutter)

Comment: @chachan Thanks! I am quite aligned with the docs, but I still suspect that the problem is with Nginx. The logging with the django project is quite extensive, I don't seem to have a request that has made through Nginx. Do you think http block in Nginx confoguration would have an effect?

Answer (score 0):

This is a conf file I use for that case. You might want to compare or follow the same approach:

```
# nginx config file for example.com

upstream django {
    server                  unix:/srv/www/app/run/app.sock;
}


server {
    listen                  80 default_server;
    server_name             example.com www.example.com;
    return                  301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen                  443 ssl;
    server_name             www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/app.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/app.key;
    return                  301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen                  443 ssl;
    server_name             example.com;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/ssl/app.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/ssl/app.key;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
    add_header              Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
    charset                 utf-8;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon;

    location /media  {
        alias               /srv/www/app/app/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias               /srv/www/app/app/collected_static;
    }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include             /srv/www/app/run/uwsgi_params;
    }

    location /api/v1/app/upload {
        uwsgi_max_temp_file_size    1M;
    }

    location /favicon.ico {
        alias               /srv/www/app/app/collected_static/img/favicon.ico;
    }
}
```

On django side, only for production environment, I do:

```
# SSL
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

That's it!

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get a chance. However, I don't see a significant difference that might cause the issue, which is what I am actually looking for. What do you think?

Comment: @HasanCanSaral I don't see any `listen 443 ssl;` statement in your file. I'd suggest to doble check docs and try to create a simpler scenario

Comment: It is in the beginning of the second server block. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's meant to be a redirect to the third block but yes, it listens to connections on that port

Comment: No, I meant there is `listen 443 ssl;` in my file. It is in the beginning of the second `server` block.

Comment: oh boy, scroll issue over here, my fault. Ok, did you check if nginx is opening that port at least locally?. Not quite sure about `@proxy_to_app` block. Would you like to try using `uwsgi_pass` instead?

Comment: Sorry I was away for quite a while. I will try your file and let you know asap, didn't have the time to work on this one.